# How do I find the relative maximum in a function?

Tags: python, numpy

To be more specific, I need to find the second highest maximum for a function. Lets say when I graph the function I get a maximum at (1,10), but what I really want is the maximum found at (4,9). Right now I am using max(function) to find the maximum value.

My Questions:

- Am I using the correct function?
- Do I use bounds? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help that can be given!

Comment: why not get the `max` of a generator about the iterable with a gen-comp filter for (1,10)?

Comment: Are you looking for 2nd max value in 2D array? Can you provide simple sample input and desired output?

Comment: Please provide more details! Is it a differentiable function with two (or more) local maxima? In that case, just solve for f'(x) = 0 and choose the second biggest arg max in that x. If you want a numerical solution, search for numerical optimization possibilities in the docs here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Comment: Providing sample code for my problem is a little tricky due to publication issues... Yes it is a 2D function. My problem is that I want to know the value of the second peak after the first one.

Comment: Here is a good representation of my problem at hand. http://cec.sonus.ca/econtact/14_2/images/ortiz_eeg.png if you look at the first plot I need to find the second maximum at .1 instead of the one at .7

Answer (score 1):

I numpy > 1.8 you can use [`np.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) to get the k-th largest element of an array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(11)
>>> np.random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
array([10,  8,  0,  3,  2,  9,  4,  1,  7,  5,  6])
>>> np.partition(a, -2) # second to last element is in the right position
array([ 5,  6,  0,  3,  2,  8,  4,  1,  7,  9, 10])
>>> np.partition(a, -2)[-2]
9
```

Comment: What does the [-2] mean after np.partition(a, -2)[-2]?

Comment: Says that my module object has no attribute 'partition'

Comment: `np.partition` is only available in numpy >= 1.8, chec what `np.__version__` you are using. The `-2` means "second from the end."

Comment: I have 2.7.6 odd... Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: You have **Python** version 2.7.6. To check numpy version: `import numpy as np; print np.__version__`

Comment: 1.7.1 That is very unfortunate and pathetic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter()` to find local maximum:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

Y, X = np.mgrid[-3:3:50j, -3:3:50j]

Z = 3 * (1 - X)**2 * np.exp(- X**2 - (Y + 1)**2) \
  - 10 * (X / 5 - X**3 - Y**5) * np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2) \
  - 1.0 / 3 * np.exp(-(X + 1)**2 - Y**2)

iy, ix = np.where(ndimage.maximum_filter(Z, size=(5, 5), mode="constant") == Z)

y, x, z = Y[iy, 0], X[0, ix], Z[iy, ix]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap="gray")
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, marker="x");
```

to find second peak, just `numpy.argsort(z)`, and get the penultimate index.

output:

[image]